# Spring Boot and Vaadin - ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I have generated Spring Boot Vaadin project at start.spring.io with just the Vaadin dependency (Maven project, Spring Boot 1.5.1, Vaadin dependency).

[image]

I have unzipped the dowloaded .zip file and imported the project to STS (File -> Import -> Existing Maven Projects). I tried to run the application but I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationObjectSupport
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1189)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:862)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:848)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:834)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:788)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
at com.example.MyvaadinApplication.main(MyvaadinApplication.java:10)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 60 more
```

The project can be build by Maven (clean install) when skipping tests. With tests enabled it fails with the same error.

I have already tried:

- to import project and run it in different IDEs (STS, Eclipse, Idea)
- run the application as Spring Boot App, Java Application, from test class
- other versions of Spring Boot (1.5.1, 1.4.4)
- different Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_65, jdk1.8.0_121)
- restart IDE

Comment: I don't know much about maven, but I do use start.spring.io myself with gradle. I cannot reproduce this error using "gradlew bootRun" on a freshly downloaded app I get a working spring boot with vaadin app. This makes me think it is probably some cache conflicting versions. Perhaps you should try to clear your maven cache if thats a thing?

Comment: Thank you for your idea. That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from p.streef I found the solution. I cleared Maven repository (more precisely I deleted content of .m2\repository\org\springframework folder where Spring .jar files are located) and run the application again. Then it worked.

---

**Edit**

It seems like frequent problem. Recently I tried to create a new Spring Boot project with Vaadin, JPA and H2 dependencies. At first I got:

```
spring boot Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
```

I deleted jars in .m2\repository\org\hibernate and run mvn clean install and got:

```
spring boot NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
```

I deleted jars in .m2\repository\org\javassist and run mvn clean install

Now it worked. So **when you get some error running newly created Spring Boot project saying that some class is missing, clean jars in your Maven repository and try it again**.